# Changing a value of an object through the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

My images have a int called hits which is intended to count the amount of times somebody has clicked on an image.  When an image is clicked on it goes to /Details/[Image ID].  My details controller has this code:

```
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    CustomButton customButton = db.CustomButtons.Find(id);
    if (customButton == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    db.CustomButtons.Find(id).Hits += 1;
    return View(customButton);
}
```

The image's hits remain at either 1 or 2 though no matter how many times they are clicked on.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are not storing the running count of hits anywhere. Every time the page comes back to the controller .Hits is 0 because every time the page reloads it re-initializes the CustomButtons and .Hits starts back at 0.

You should store the current number of Hits in the Model and send the Model back with the View. In the View you can take the current number of Hits from the Model and store it back in .Hits. Then when sent to the controller, increment Hits and store it back in the Model and return the new Model with the View.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I had to add db.SaveChanges(); to the next line after increasing hits by one.

Comment: Precisely. `db.CustomButtons.Find(id).Hits += 1;` does nothing by itself other than specify a desire for the `Hits` value of your `CustomButton` object with id `id` to be increased by one. That value is not actually converted and saved into your database until you invoke `db.SaveChanges();`.